# Unbind all Models in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

Is there any function to `unbind` all associative Models before `find()` in CakePHP?

```
$this->Model1->unbindModel(array('hasMany'=>array('Model2'),'belongsTo'=>array('Model3')));
```

I want to get result from `Model1` only. But as I have many models, so I don't want to use `unbindModel` like this separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply set the model recursive to -1

```
$this->ModelName->recursive = -1;
$assets = $this->ModelName->find('all');
debug($assets);
```

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
$this->Model1->recursive = -1;
```

Comment: Isn't the same as what I said?